# Blank screen after compiling

Tags: magento2, setup-di-compile, code-generation, white-screen

After putting the site into production mode and running the compiler, the site just loads a blank white page. I've tried disabling all third party modules and it has not helped. I have all error logging enabled, but nothing is logged. I've narrowed it down to something in the generated metadata, as deleting that folder gets the site working again. I've struggled with this for the past couple days and I'm at a loss. Anyone have any clue?

Here is the source for the blank page that is displayed:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head >
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>
    <title></title>
    <link  rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/pub/static/version1519935733/frontend/_view/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
    <link  rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/pub/static/version1519935733/frontend/_view/en_US/Magento_Theme/favicon.ico" />
</head>
<body data-container="body" data-mage-init='{"loaderAjax": {}, "loader": { "icon": "https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/pub/static/version1519935733/frontend/_view/en_US/images/loader-2.gif"}}' class="cms-index-index page-layout-1column">
</body>
</html>
```

Magento 2.2.2

Comment: add `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to index.php file and check error log file located in var folder

Answer (score 6):

**Just follow :** to debug blank white screen and CSS,JS page load design issue.

1. **open terminal**  run following command

> cd  magento-root-folder
>   `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`

then
 **don't compile** just deploy

`php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`

and

`php bin/magento indexer:reindex`

> Make sure “rewrite_module” on your production server.

`chown -R www-data:www-data /var/www/html/magento2`

check & set file permission also

'chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2'

delete all from `var/cache`

Comment: `chmod -R 777 /var/www/html/magento2` ... seriously?

Answer (score 2):

after setup:di:compile - all page blank

I have the same problem. If you are 2.2.X, go to /generated/metadata, rename global.php to for example global1.php and it should be work again.

It is not a solution. Just to share the hints.

Try to use multiple version 2.2.2, 2.2.3, even 2.3 Develop - Clean install, setup:di:compile - blank page

And I am using Macbook Pro in windows 10 (I am not sure if this is a problem and PHP 7.1.15

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and this happens because of folder permissions..

You need to give pub folder rights permissions, on Linux

```
chmod 775 -R pub
chmod 775 -R var
chmod 775 -R generated
```

the -R means recursive, it will affect also sub folders and files.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that you don't have versioning issue. Some time when you delete static folder from pub then it will re-create.

**So please check your static folder have the .htaccess and deployed_versions.txt file**.