# M2 2.3.1 White screen on Product page after compile

Tags: magento2, php-7

I'm experiencing a white screen of death on product detail pages (both simple & grouped) after running the **php bin/magento setup:di:compile** command. I've tracked it down to the global.php file in the generated/metadata folder. If I rename this file then the pages display absolutely fine. How can I troubleshoot this issue, ? So that global.php is generated correctly. The white screen gives no obvious error messages and IO cannot see any relevant entries in the log files..

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/215701/blank-screen-after-compiling

Comment: tried this renaming global.php to global1.php works but I would like to ficx the actual issue.

Comment: on debug mode and check what error will shown..
Or again Upgrade command then then don't compile just deploy

php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f then reindex and clear cache.

Comment: You can uncomment this line **ini_set('display_errors', 1);**  in your app/bootstrap.php file ? and then refresh your product page you'll get error message there

Comment: ah ha.. tahnks .. This error is returned now..  Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot instantiate abstract class Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView in /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php:116 Stack trace: #0 /vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/Compiled.php(108): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\AbstractFactory->createObject('Magento\\Catalog...', Array) #1 //vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php(70): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\\Catalog...')

Comment: #2 //app/design/frontend/Concrete/speed/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml(24): Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\ObjectManager->get('Magento\\Catalog...') #3 //vendor/magento/framework/View/TemplateEngine/Php.php(59): include('/home/www/Magen...') #4 /vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Templ in //vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/Factory/AbstractFactory.php on line 116

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever you will get blank page (white screen), you can just uncomment below line in this file.

> app/bootstrap.php

```
#ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

Remove **#** sign in this line..

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
```

You'll get error message on your screen after doing this.

Hope this will help you!

Comment: yep ! thanks error above,,

Comment: Can you please share this file's code with me ? So I can debug more..

app/design/frontend/Concrete/speed/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml

Comment: are you able to find out your issue ?